# rollback buttons visibility with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your support with one question. Maybe someone have ideas.

I have a table with buttons `visibility: hidden`, when mouse on the table
 `visibility: hidden` changes to `visibility: visible`. This code you can find in function `changePosition`.

How to rollback to `visibility: hidden` if mouse not on the table?

My code is bellow 
Here is example how it works now [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yaaqgz0m/)

Thank you in advance!

```js
window.onload = addEvents;

function addEvents() {

  let cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");

  for (element = 0; element < cells.length; element++) {
    cells[element].onmouseover = function() {
      changePosition(this)
    };
  }
  document.querySelector(".square-buttons_add-col").addEventListener("click", appendCol)
  document.querySelector(".square-buttons_add-row").addEventListener("click", appendRow)
  document.querySelector(".square-buttons_del-col").addEventListener("click", deleteCol)
  document.querySelector(".square-buttons_del-row").addEventListener("click", deleteRow)
}







var currentRow = 0;
var currentCol = 0;

function changePosition(currentCell) {
  let top = currentCell.offsetTop;
  let minusRow = document.querySelector(".square-buttons_del-row");
  let left = currentCell.offsetLeft;
  let minusCol = document.querySelector(".square-buttons_del-col");
  minusCol.style.left = (left + 1) + 'px';
  minusRow.style.top = (top + 1) + 'px';
  currentCol = currentCell.cellIndex;  
  currentRow = currentCell.parentElement.rowIndex;
  minusCol.style.visibility = "visible";
  minusRow.style.visibility = "visible";
    

  
}

function deleteRow() {
  let table = document.querySelector(".square-table");
  let deleteRowButton = document.querySelector(".square-buttons_del-row");
  let deleteRowButtonTop = deleteRowButton.style.top;
  if (table.rows.length > 1) {
    table.deleteRow(currentRow);
  }  
}



function deleteCol() {
  let table = document.querySelector(".square-table");
  for (row = 0; row < table.rows.length; row++) {
    if (table.rows[row].cells.length > 1) {
      table.rows[row].deleteCell(currentCol);
    }

  }

}


function appendRow() {
  var table = document.querySelector(".square-table");
  var new_row = table.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
  for (cell = 0; cell < new_row.children.length; cell++){
      new_row.children[cell].onmouseover = function() {
      changePosition(this)}
  }
  table.appendChild(new_row);

}


function appendCol() {
  var table = document.querySelector(".square-table");
  for (row = 0; row < table.rows.length; row++) {      
    var new_cell = table.rows[0].cells[0].cloneNode(true);
    new_cell.onmouseover = function() {changePosition(this)}
      
    table.rows[row].appendChild(new_cell)
    
  }
}
```

```css
/* general */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.square-page__items {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


button.square-buttons {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
}


table.square-table {
  border: 1px solid #48aae6;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


div.square-cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #48aae6;
}




/*buttons*/

button.square-buttons_add-col {
  background-color: #f3a500;
  /*background-image: url("../images/minus.png");*/
  top: 3px;
  right: -52px;    
}


button.square-buttons_del-col {
  background-color: #b20000;
 /* background-image: url("../images/minus.png");*/
  top: -52px;
  right: 2px;
  visibility: hidden;
}


button.square-buttons_add-row {
  background-color: #f3a500;
  /*background-image: url("../images/plus.pngss");*/
  bottom: -52px;
  left: 3px;
}


button.square-buttons_del-row {
  background-color: #b20000;
  /*background-image: url("../images/minus.png");*/
  left: -52px;
  bottom: 2px;
  visibility: hidden;
 
}



/*buttons during action*/

button.square-buttons_add-col_active:hover {
  background-color: #f6c052;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

button.square-buttons_del-col_active:hover {
  background-color: #ca4c49;
  cursor:  pointer; 
  display: block;
}

button.square-buttons_add-row_active:hover {
  background-color: #f6c052;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.square-buttons_del-row_active:hover {
  background-color: #ca4c49;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <body>

    <div class="square-page__items">


        <!--start table 4x4-->

        <table class="square-table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">1 1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">1 2</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">1 3</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">1 4</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
              <div class="square-cell">2 1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">2 2</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">2 3</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">2 4</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
              <div class="square-cell">3 1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">3 2</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">3 3</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">3 4</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
              <div class="square-cell">4 1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">4 2</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">4 3</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="square-cell">4 4</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
            
        </table>

      
       
        <button class="square-buttons square-buttons_add-col square-buttons_add-col_active"></button>
        
        <button class="square-buttons square-buttons_del-col square-buttons_del-col_active"></button>
      
        <button class="square-buttons square-buttons_add-row square-buttons_add-row_active"></button>
        
        <button class="square-buttons square-buttons_del-row square-buttons_del-row_active"></button>


    </div>


  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
  let minusCol = document.querySelector(".square-buttons_del-col");
  let minusRow = document.querySelector(".square-buttons_del-row");
  document.querySelector(".square-table").addEventListener("mouseleave",function() {
     minusCol.style.visibility = "hidden";
     minusRow.style.visibility = "hidden";
  });
```

place it in an `addEvents()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can either register an event listener on `mouseout` (which is fired when the mouse leaves the corresponding element), or, and I suggest this option, do that with CSS only.

In CSS, that would be:

```
.yourclass {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.yourclass:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

If you really want to do it in JS, in your `addEvents` function:

```
for (element = 0; element < cells.length; element++) {
    cells[element].onmouseover = function() {
      changePosition(this)
    };

    /* ADD THIS */
    cells[element].onmouseout = function() {
      /* call here a function which set visibility to hidden */
    };
}
```

Comment: the task is do it only with js, tanks I will try now